# Paypal TLSv1.2 Sandbox

Tags: paypal, dns

Paypal upgraded to TLSv1.2. We are trying to verify our system integration with Paypal using  https://tlstest.paypal.com (as mentioned in Paypal site).
Accessing this url directly or through Response.Redirect works fine but posting data to this url results in the following error:

> Service Unavailable - DNS failure
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request. Please try again later.
>   Reference #11.bb070f17.1459958479.7d82fa3

Does the above url accept the post data?

Answer (score 0):

That URL will not allow posted data, its purely to test the connection from your server to PayPal's.